# Hibernate retrieving/showing deleted objects even though it is commited

Tags: java, hibernate

I was using Hibernate 3.3 and recently upgraded to version 4.3.11.
After moving to this version, I started noticing a strange problem.

1. Objects that I delete shows up every now and then.
2. Objects that I added newly show up only rarely.

It looks as if the current state of the db is shown only on the exact connection pool being used to delete it.

Below is the snippet of the code used to save

```
    Transaction tx = null;

    try {
        Session session = hibSessFact.currentSession();
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(o);
        tx.commit();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        hibSessFact.closeSession();
        System.out.println("session closed");
    }
```

The below is how the data is retrieved

```
        try{
           Session session = hibSessFact.currentSession();
           Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(MyObject.class);
           List objList = crit.list();
           System.out.println("returned list");
           return objList;
        }catch(Exception e){
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
           hibSessFact.closeSession();
        }
```

P.S.: The same happens with object retrieval when new objects are added. It shows up only intermittently, exactly every 3rd request.

Update: ThreadLocal is used to create session using HibernateSessionFactory.

Comment: How do you delete? Do you set a flag or is it a row delete? If its a flag check your query, If its a row delete please add the code used for delete.

Comment: Exactly similar to how the object is saved using `session.delete(myObj)`

Comment: Try adding session.flush() after session.delete();

Comment: session.flush doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you debug and check if the row is actually getting deleted after `session.flush()`?The flush must actually sync the underlying cache with the db.

Comment: Even without the flush the row is deleted from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of currentSession used to get session make use of openSession() as below:

```
Session session = hibSessFact.openSession();
```

Otherwise, add the below property in hibernate configuration.

```
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Comment: The second option worked for me. However, I ran into another issue where criteria would throw an exception that a transaction is required to execute query. Though odd, I modified my middle layer class that begins the transaction for these queries.